# LocalDateTime to specific timezone

Tags: java, java-time

I have a `localdatetime` object that is in UTC. I want to convert into IST.
How can I do that?

```
LocalDateTime dateTimeOfAfterFiveDays = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(after5,0,ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: Maybe use `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to track a moment.

Comment: Assuming `after5` is a count of seconds since the epoch, start from `Instant.ofEpochSecond(after5)` instead. And depending on where `after5` comes from, you may want to produce that as an `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` or other object rather than a naked count.

Answer (score 29):

Since Java 8 the date/time API is pretty easy to work with.

In your case:

```
// your local date/time with no timezone information
LocalDateTime localNow = LocalDateTime.now();
// setting UTC as the timezone
ZonedDateTime zonedUTC = localNow.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
// converting to IST
ZonedDateTime zonedIST = zonedUTC.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
```

You'll see a difference in the time (and possibly the date) between `zonedUTC` and `zonedIST`, reflecting the time zone offset between the two.

Note the usage of [withZoneSameInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant(java.time.ZoneId)) here, e.g. as opposed to `withZoneSameLocal`.

Comment: Wrong class. `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. I cannot think of a use-case where `LocalDateTime.now` is ever the right thing.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` here because OP used it. It's not hard to agree `LocalDateTime` has no tz information, that's pretty much in the name. I'm initializing `LocalDateTime.now()` because it represents a "now" date/time on this system, with no specific tz attached. The next step is to decide that "here the tz is UTC" and decorating the original object with it. The third step is obtaining a new date time with the tz offset betwen UTC and IST. While `LocalDateTime.now` usage is indeed unrealistic in real life, this is obviously just an example focusing on the difference between local and zoned...

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr

Use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), not [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) for tracking a moment.

```
Instant                                         // Represents a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.
.ofEpochSecond(
    myCountOfWholeSecondsSinceStartOf1970UTC    // Internally, time is tracked as a count of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z plus a fractional second as nanoseconds.
)                                               // Returns a moment in UTC.
.atZone(                                        // Adjust from UTC to another time zone. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )                 // Specify time zone name in `Continent/Region` format, never 2-4 letter pseudo-zone.
)                                               // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                                     // Generate a string representing the value of this `ZonedDateTime` in standard ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

## Wrong class

> LocalDateTime dateTimeOfAfterFiveDays = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(after5,0,ZoneOffset.UTC);

`LocalDateTime` is the **wrong class** to use here. This class cannot represent a moment. It lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. A `LocalDateTime` holds just a date and a time-of-day, say noon on the 23rd of January this year. But we have no idea if what was intended was noon in Tokyo, noon in Kolkata, noon in Paris, or noon in Montréal — all of these are hours apart, very different moments.

## `Instant`

To represent a moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

Apparently you have a count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( count ) ;
```

## `ZoneId` & `ZonedDateTime`

To see this value through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, you can use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to convert [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) with respect to a specific [ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html). Considering your example, the conversion could be implemented as follows:

```java
ZoneId istZoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
LocalDateTime dateTimeOfAfterFiveDays = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(after5,0,ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeOfAfterFiveDays = dateTimeOfAfterFiveDays.atZone(istZoneId);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Note that `atZone` will not alter the date/time. It will only set a timezone on a non-zoned (local) date/time. So if it's 15:30 in the local date/time that needs to be interpreted as UTC within context, `atZone` on that object will only decorate `15:30` with the desired timezone, i.e. the resulting `ZonedDateTime` will still be 15:30, only in IST.

Comment: Doesn't ```LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(after5,0,ZoneOffset.UTC)``` take care of interpreting the local date/time as UTC?

Comment: @LorenzoAddazi You are throwing away the zone/offset information by using `LocalDateTime`. You might get away with it in this situation, but it makes no sense. `ZonedDateTime` is the class for this work, not `LocalDateTime`.