How to store LocalDateTime UTC in Java spring
In my Java spring app, if I want to store a LocalDateTime field in UTC. I know I should follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56361517 here where it says to convert the LocalDateTime to UTC with a ZonedDateTime, but is there a better way to store in UTC like setting my Postgres db timezone as UTC?

Why would setting your db timezone to UTC affect the data? If a db were to transform my data just by changing settings, it would probably be a cause for concern

@Chaosfire Instant is not mapped in JDBC. Your Comment should have suggested OffsetDateTime.

@BasilBourque I was not aware of that, thanks for clarification!

@Chaosfire You may have used a JDBC driver whose implementer chose to map Instant to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. But that mapping is not defined in the JDBC specification. So any code using that extra behavior would not be portable to other JDBC drivers.

LocalDateTime is wrong class
If you want to track a moment, a specific point on the timeline, you cannot use LocalDateTime. That class represents a date with time of day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset. A LocalDateTime is inherently ambiguous.
For example… If we record an event as 2024-08-22 19:54:58, does that mean it happened at 7 PM in Tokyo Japan, 7 PM in Toulouse France, or 7 PM in Toledo Ohio US? Those are three very different moments, several hours apart. That is the ambiguity of a LocalDateTime object.
If we add the letter Z, that changes everything. Per ISO 8601 and aviation/military tradition, that letter (pronounced “Zulu”) means an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. So with Z, 2024-08-22T19:54:58Z, or 2024-08-22T19:54:58+00:00, we know exactly when that event occurred. That is the meaning of an Instant object (and an OffsetDateTime object).
Use OffsetDateTime
For a moment, use Instant, OffsetDateTime, or ZonedDateTime.
For exchange with a SQL database column of a type akin to the SQL Standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, you must use OffsetDateTime in JDBC 4.2+.
If you are certain the date and time is meant to represent a moment as seen in UTC (offset of zero), do this:
OffsetDateTime odt = myLocalDateTime.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;

Persist:
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;

Retrieve:
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;

Record current moment
When recording the creation or update of data, capture the current moment with Instant.
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;

To record that to database, convert to OffsetDateTime.
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;

Explicit time zone

setting my Postgres db timezone as UTC

No need to bother with the database session’s current default time zone.  Write your code to explicitly state its desired/expected time zone or offset. Notice how the code above does not care about the session default, the JVM’s current default, not the host OS’ current default.

So even for my updated_at and created_at it's not recommended to use localdatetime?

@user9132502 No, certainly not. If we record your comment as 2024-08-22 19:54:58, does that mean you posted at 7 PM in Tokyo Japan, 7 PM in Toulouse France, or 7 PM in Toledo Ohio US? Those are three very different moments, several hours apart. If you hover your mouse over the "33 mins ago" label next to your name on that Comment, you will see that date and time along with the letter Z. Per ISO 8601, and aviation/military tradition, that letter pronounced “Zulu” means an offset from the temporal meridian of UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. So with Z we know exactly what moment you posted.

Thanks a lot! Can I be sure that OffsetDateTime will be stored in UTC, or should I explicitly tell it?

@user9132502  depends on the database. Postgres automatically adjusts inputs to UTC when storing an input to a column of type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. See documentation. But I would nevertheless specify UTC in my Java code to clearly communicate my intentions and my understanding to later programmers reading my code.

Thanks, I guess using val utcTime: OffsetDateTime = someOffsetDateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC) before saving to db would work perfectly?

Ignore my last question sorry. I put all my fields as OffsetDateTime in my JPA models, is it better than ZonedDateTime?

ZonedDateTime is not mapped in JDBC. I highly recommend reading the JDBC spec rather than guessing.
